# quad monitors and DWM resource errors

Tags: display, dwm

For a couple years now I've been wrestling with a multi monitor setup, to clear the Desktop Windows Manager resource errors.  Currently I'm running 3x1900x1200 and 1x1900x1080 driven by 2xHD5770, on a z68 board with i7-3770k.  MY WEI for graphics is 7.4, and 7.8 for the CPU/RAM, so its not a resource issue.  I'm running these monitors all in extended desktop mode.  My question is, how do I clear those DWM errors?

From what I've read, win7 doesn't have the limit on max number of open windows that XP did, and the resources for DWM and WDDM are greatly improved and will utilize discrete graphics card resources.  When monitoring my GPU via GPU-z, its seems I'm barely using the cards.  I could throw in a couple PCIE3 cards, such as the AMD HD7770, but I don't have any reason to think they'll improve things.  I'm now out of ideas and have to question some assumptions, like is DWM/WDDM really able to handle multiple extended displays, and if so, what is the max.  What is the max resolution or largest desktop DWM can draw widows on?  In short, where are the graphic  resources falling short, and why?

Error log:
The Desktop Window Manager is experiencing heavy resource contention.
       Reason      :       CPU resources are over-utilized.
       Diagnosis    :      A sharp degradation in Desktop Window Manager responsiveness was observed.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, while Microsoft doesn't seem to want to own, that DWM (Desktop Window Manager) has resource issues, it's been my experience that the service, essential to the Aero-glass appearance on Windows 7, can easily be "maxed out" if there is too much pixel real estate in front of you.  My current environment uses two dedicated graphics adapters (AMD HD 5450 and AMD HD 6450) for 3 1600x1200 monitors. And the Aero-glass appearance can only be maintained for a short time before the system automatically shifts to "Basic" appearance mode (and a varienty of Event ID errors, 9024/9025/9026, are logged in the Application log). Restarting the DWM service re-enables the Aero-glass mode, but that will only last a short time.

You can get an idea of the resources being exhausted through Microsoft's SysInternal's Process Explorer tool; a tool which provides far greater details about each Window's process and is available as a free download from [technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). Once running this tool, select the dwm.exe process, right-click for Properties, then select the **GPU Graph** option. You will see how close to maximum the resources are for this service.